# Get data from datatable form one column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

The query below will get data from a column to see if the data contains a certain string.

This is string is found in that column I would like to select all of the data within them rows. For example in the the datatable the will be a row with `age[10-20]` and based on this input string it should output all of the row the string is `age`

The code does not return any data, nor are there any errors. Is it possible to select a column based on the index ?

```
var result = excelDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(data => data.Field<String>(0).StartsWith(queryString));
```

Data input 1

```
Age
```

Data in `DataTable`

```
Age[0-8]         1           1                1
Age[9-11]        2           2                2
season[winter]   4           4                4
```

Based on the input I want to return

```
Age[0-8]         1           1                1
Age[9-11]        2           2                2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the column name with Select method.

```
var result = importedExcelData.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(data => data.Field<String>("All Respondents")
              .Contains(first))
              .Select(c=>c.Field<String>(0)).ToList();
```

Comment: this is based on the column name i would like to use a index... not the actual name as it may change...

Comment: but in the where statement i am still refernaceing the row

Comment: but the string isnt the actual indes

Comment: Replace ("All Respondents") with the index of the column, which I don't know, it may not be 0 in this case.

Comment: so what can the index be... how can i get the index

Answer (score 2):

The [`Field` extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method works also with the index of the column:

```
var result = importedExcelData.AsEnumerable()
                              .Where(r=> r.Field<String>(0).Contains(first));
```

Comment: var result = excelDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(data => data.Field<String>(0).StartsWith(queryString));                 
i am using the above and does not return anything

Comment: So now you know why it's better to provide sample data and an expected result. Otherwise it's difficult to understand the real requirement. _" the will be a row with "age[10-20]" "_ is not helpful, a row contains not a string but fields and these field may contain a string.

Comment: Are `1           1                1` different columns in the row or are these different rows? Display the sample data as table or - even better - additionally show the code which adds the sample data to the DataTable(including the DataColumns). Then everybody could even test the answer.